# Science Themed Logic Problem

Tags: logical-deduction

I have this question as extra credit for my chemistry class. Im passed the deadline for EC so i don't even care about that, the answer is just driving me crazy! No one else has figured it out that i know of. Here's the logic problem:

EC: Science Friction

The science department at Rasputin High School is brimming with controversy.  Each teacher is currently angry with a different teacher for a different reason ( in one case, because another teacher told a joke at his or her expense). Discover each person's subject, the teacher with whom he or she is angry, and why.

1. No pair of teachers is angry at each other.
2. The chemistry teacher is angry with a man.
3. Mr. Hogarth is angry because another teacher commented on his weight.
4. The physics teacher is angry with Ms. Watson.
5. A woman is angry with another teacher who received a better class schedule.
6. A man is angry at Ms. Kessler, who teaches computers.
7. The person who is angry because another teacher scratched his or her car in the parking lot doesn't teach chemistry or physics.
8. Mr. Forbes doesn't teach biology.

Comment: There appear to be four teachers,four reasons,four subjects. I think it will work with one of those grid things with ticks and crosses in that we used to do in kids'logic problems...

Comment: @n_palum 4 teachers, 2 males 2 females. You can tell by their pronouns (Mr. or Ms.)

Comment: @Kit-Ginerva I tried the logic grid but with the added factor of teachers being mad at eachother, i couldnt make it work

Comment: I think there are two (very similar) solutions.

Answer (score 8):

**Solution:**

> Chemistry teacher is Ms Watson, and is angry at Mr Hogarth (class schedules)
>  Physics teacher is Mr Forbes, and is angry at Ms Watson (joke)
>  Biology teacher is Mr Hogarth, and is angry at Ms Kessler (weight comment)
>  Computers teacher is Ms Kessler, and is angry at Mr Forbes  (car scratched)

**Logic:**

> Physics teacher angry at Ms Watson, a female (#4)
>  A man is angry at Ms Kessler, a female, who teaches computers. (#6)
>  Chemistry teacher is angry at a man. (#2)
>  Two of chemistry, physics, and biology are taught by men.  (#6)
>  Physics teacher is not Ms Watson, so must be male. (#4)
>  Biology teacher is not Mr Forbes (#8)
>  The man who is not the Physics teacher is angry at Ms Kessler (#4, #2, #6)
>  (So male teachers are angry at Ms Kessler and Ms Watson)
>  Chemistry teacher cannot be male: angry at a man (#2) and both men are angry at females.
>  So Physics and Biology teachers are male, Chemistry and Computers are female. (Elimination)
>  Physics is Mr Forbes, Biology is Mr Hogarth (#8, #3)
>  Chemistry is Ms Watson, Computers is Ms Kessler (#4, #6)
>  Mr Forbes is angry at Ms Watson.  (#4)
>  Mr Hogarth is angry at Ms Kessler. (#6)
>  Ms Watson is angry at Mr Hogarth (#2, #1)
>  Ms Kessler is angry at Mr Forbes (Elimination)
>  Mr Hogarth is angry because of the comment about his weight (#3)
>  Ms Kessler is angry because her car was scratched (#7, elimination)
>  Ms Watson is angry because of class schedules (#5, elimination)
>  Mr Forbes is angry because of a joke (Elimination)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Try a grid like this: [(link to online solver)](http://www.jsingler.de/apps/logikloeser/?language=en#(at:s,items:!(!(chemistry,physics,biology,computers),!(%27Mr.%20Hogarth%27,%27Mr.%20Forbes%27,%27Ms.%20Watson%27,%27Ms.%20Kessler%27),!(%27angry%20at%20Mr.%20Hogarth%27,%27angry%20at%20Mr.%20Forbes%27,%27angry%20at%20Ms.%20Watson%27,%27angry%20at%20Ms.%20Kessler%27),!(weight,%27class%20sched.%27,car,joke),!(man,man,woman,woman)),ms:t,n:!(),nc:5,ni:4,p:!(b0e0,b1e1,b2e2,b3e3),v:0))

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> chemistry       Ms. Watson     angry at Mr. Hogarth       class sched.
> physics         Mr. Forbes     angry at Ms. Watson        joke
> biology         Mr. Hogarth    angry at Ms. Kessler       weigh
> computers       Ms. Kessler    angry at Mr. Forbes        car
> ```

Comment: view this as a grid lol

Comment: I agree *but* I think everything also works if K is angry at W instead of F. (Perhaps there was meant to be an assumption that everyone has exactly one person angry at them?)

Comment: ah, no, it does say everyone is angry with a different teacher so all is well.